# Blender doesn't launch unless I'm sharing my screen

Tags: error

I'm having an issue with blender that has happened for a while now but has only become serious recently. Previously, every so often (maybe every 30 minutes or so), both of my monitors would go black for two seconds or so, before blender crashes. As of recent, I have not been able to start the program at all. I notice that other applications have started to do the same thing, such as the Ryzen driver software. Whenever it crashes (which is now every time I try to launch), there is no error message or other window that pops open.

However, blender and other applications with the similar issue run perfectly while I am in a call on Discord and sharing my screen (specifically sharing my screen). I initially thought that it would be an issue with hardware, but a) my hardware is relatively new and b) the applications work just fine while I'm sharing my screen, which just uses more hardware.

Specs:

AMD Ryzen 2700x (3.7 ghz)

16gb 3200 mhz ram (Corsair)

Nvidia RTX 2070 (Gigabyte)

Gigabyte x470 motherboard

I have reinstalled blender and all other applications with the same issue, restarted my computer when the issue occurs, reinstalled both of the latest Nvidia and AMD drivers, and even checked my cpu and gpu temperatures while using blender (nothing unusual). I've also read through various other questions people have with crashing, but none seem similar to the issues I have. I also have blender configured to render with my gpu, which I am sure of since the task manager reports little to no usage of cpu usage while rendering.

Has anyone else had this same issue? Maybe the current drivers don't work well with blender, but the most mysterious part of the whole thing to me is that I can use blender endlessly if I'm in a call on discord while sharing my screen, but the moment I stop sharing my screen, it crashes. Any solutions, ideas, or comments of similar issues would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like GPU driver issue or a bug. Maybe try previous GPU driver versions...

Comment: I figured it out. I had the NVIDIA Game Ready Driver updated, but not the NVIDIA Studio Driver. I can open the applications just fine now. Thanks for the input though, I'll keep it in mind if the issue arises in the future.